# Does median of a set changes if we repeat the sample n times where n is positive integer?

Tags: math, statistics, median, discrete-mathematics

Will the median be changed if the sample is duplicated. I don't have any full proof method to tell for every case. But for very common sense it should never change since each value is getting duplicated.
Adding same numbers upper and down , so in odd terms it will not affect at all. Similarly with even terms since the middle segment now comprised of two elements will not be disturbed by copying of elements above it and below it and number will remain even only so its own duplication will also not disturb the middle segment

Comment: This is more of a [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) question than a programming one, isn't it?

Comment: Are you saying that a sample of size N is transformed into a sample of size kN by duplicating each element so you have k of each; or are you saying you increase the sample to kN elements by taking another (k-1)N values of the random variable? If the former, the median is unchanged. If the latter, the median changes (probably).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding and subtracting the same values, the median should not change. If you forget to add or subtract one number then it will for sure change the median. Also, make sure to remember the sample size (n) increased. When calculating the median remember that :)